# Book about kids sent back in time on a plane

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, childrens-novel

I was reading a book, it may or may not have been part of a series. It was about a group of friends who later discover that they are adopted. Through some other adventures, they also discover that they were actually originally from some other time period. In the future, a company called "Tachyon Travels" or something similar would travel back in time and get children for rich people to adopt. It started out small, such as by saving a child that was about to be killed, but the company eventually moved on to abducting more famous individuals. At some point, some sort of authority decided to put an end to it and put these children on an airplane to send them back in time. When the plane landed in the past, one of the flight attendants saw that it was filled with infants as a result of the time travel. That's all I remember.
Any ideas what the book was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*Found*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Missing_(novel_series)) by Margaret Peterson Haddix. It was part of a series of novels where children are abducted, often by plane, and sent to the future.

> One night a plane appeared out of nowhere, the only passengers aboard: thirty-six babies. As soon as they were taken off the plane, it vanished. Now, thirteen years later, two of those children are receiving sinister messages, and they begin to investigate their past. Their quest to discover where they really came from leads them to a conspiracy that reaches from the far past to the distant future--and will take them hurtling through time

Notably, the company in question was called Tachyon Travel.

> On the side of the jet, she was surprised to see a strange
> insignia: TACHYON TRAVEL, it said, some airline Angela had never heard
> of. Was that a private charter company maybe? And then, while she was
> staring at it, the words suddenly changed into the familiar
> wing-in-the-clouds symbol of Sky Trails.

[image]